# How do create a SQL Server query which reassigns inventory between shops with excess/demand of stock to balance it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, data-modeling, inventory

My scenario is as follows: 
I have shops with products where analysis indicated some products are in demand in one shops and in excess in inventory on the others.
How do I go about creating SQL Server query which would return me how many products should I send from which shop to which shop to **minimize number of transfers**.

Sample data would look as follows:

```
ShopID      Product req_change
------      ------- ----------
001         pencil  -20
002         notepad -15
006         notepad -8
007         notepad -5
003         pencil  5
004         pencil  7
003         notepad 20
005         notepad 13
```

I would expect that query to return following:

```
ShopFrom    Product Qty ShopTo
--------    ------  --- ------
001         pencil  5   003
001         pencil  7   004
002         notepad 15  003
007         notepad 5   003
006         notepad 8   005
```

It will happend that perfect demand and excess may not match but then you transfer what you can.
This is wrecking my had a bit so I will appreciate any ideas how to bite this.
Thanks
Wiciu

Comment: I'm not saying it is impossible, but you should consider processing this data with a mathematical model instead of a single query which will make a simple problem complicated.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: forgot to state that I am working on SQL Server 2012, thanks for asking

Comment: @Pinx0: I was thinking SQL query may not be a bast tool here. Would you like to suggest any other tool. Excel? or something more sophisticated.

Comment: Excel will do, it's not a very complicated problem. If you require more power you can switch to a linear programming solver like GUSEK (free) or Gurobi (commercial).